# como puedo añadir una imagen desde el servicio mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Muy buenas
hasta ahora en mi pagina presento 6 imagenes de una galeria dentro de mi proyecto adjunto el codigo:
mi controlador

```
    public ActionResult Partialmagen()
    {
        //ScriptController script = new ScriptController();
        //script.DirJS = "/Scripts/validacion.js";
        //script.FunJS = "UsuarioImagenPartial.Index();";
        //Codigoimagen1;
         var model = new Imagen_prueba()           
        {

        Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Imagenes"))
                 .Select(fn => "~/Imagenes/" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
         };
      //  ViewBag.Images1 = Session["Generarimagen"];

        return View(model);

       // var f1 = PartialView("Partialmagen"/*, script*/);
       // return f1;

    }
```

Mi clase:

```
public class Imagen_prueba

 {
       public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }      
 }

el codigo de la pagina donde genero las imagenes


@model Oronet.Web.Areas.Acceso.Models.Imagen_prueba

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Partialmagen";
  //  Layout = "~/Areas/Acceso/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<div class="col s8 offset-s2">
    <h4 class="center-align">Selecciona Su Imagen</h4>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="ListImg">
            @{
                int cont = 0;
               // foreach (var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
               // {
                    // foreach (var image2 in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Codigoimagen1)

                    foreach (var image in Model.Images)
                     {
                    //var str = ViewBag.Images1 + "";
                    //var pad = "000";
                    //var ans = pad.Substring(0, pad.Length - str.Length) + str;
                    //ans = "IMG" + ans + ".jpg";
                    cont++;
                    if (cont <= 6)
                    {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(image)" class="imagen" id="@cont" onclick="UsuarioImagenPartial.SelectImg()" />
                            @*<img src="@Url.Content(@ans)" class="imagen" id="@cont" onclick="UsuarioImagenPartial.SelectImg()" />
                            <a> <img class="imagen" src="~/Imagenes/@ans" /> </a>*@
                            @*<img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" />*@
                            @*<div class="col s2"><a> <img onclick = "UsuarioImagenPartial.SelectImg(this)" class="imagen" id="@cont" src="~/Imagenes/@ans" /> </a></div>*@
                        }
                  //  }
                }
            }

        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un servicio que me devuelve un codigo de tipo entero: me devuelve un digamos, 15 , en mi carpeta de galeria la imagen existe bajo este nombre IMG015.JPG, como puedo hacer esa referencia para mostrarla en mi pagina?

Comment: Para poder entender mejor, del arreglo con las imagenes rescatadas del directorio quieres elegir solo una en la vista de detalles?

Comment: si exactamente, eso